# How to store textboxes into an array during runtime

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

The Situation is like this:
I have multiple textboxes. On the occurrence of textChanged event the textbox should be stored in the array so that I can use it in further functions.

```
private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t;
        t = (TextBox)sender;
    }
```

Now I have the textbox which was responsible for the event. Now I have to store this and more to come in an array so that these can be accessed elsewhere in another function.

Comment: Why do you need the textbox itself, and not only the value? Also, what is not working?

Comment: You probably already have private fields that can be used to access your controls (assuming Windows Forms, their declarations should reside in a Form.Designer.cs file). It'd also help if you clarified what you want to do with these UI controls later.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off using a `List<TextBox>` rather than a `TextBox[]` array.  But as Msonic implied, it's hard to propose a solution without knowing the underlying problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could throw it in a list if ya like. Not sure why you would really want to do this though...

```
List<TextBox> txtbxList = new List<TextBox>();

private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox t;
        t = (TextBox)sender;
        txtbxList.Add(t);
    }
```

Comment: I would like to access the textboxes in a loop and compare the text of the textboxes to a series of values according to the index.

Comment: @Slump: This code adds the same textbox to the list again and again every time its text changes.

Comment: @AnkitYadav: Use a HashSet<TextBox> to add your text boxes to, then you can later enumerate the set and retrieve your text boxes to do the comparisons. However, there is almost always a better way to do what you want; care to add an even larger context (what you *really* want to achieve)?

Comment: @Alan: Thanks for telling that. But I can handle that because once the value is read the textbox is disabled so there would be no duplicate value

Comment: @AnkitYadav: OK, fine. Not meaning to be bashful, but this was a crucial bit of info that you did not include in the question. Under normal circumstances (e.g. text boxes that are *not* disabled immediately upon reading their contents), the accepted solution would clearly lead you down a wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

I dont know why you need to store your TextBoxes in a List or Array but you can use the generic List for that.

> Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index. Provides methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists.

#### Sample

```
List<TextBox> myTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
// Add a TextBox
myTextBoxes.Add(myTextBox);
// get a TextBox by Name
TextBox t = myTextBoxes.Where(x => x.Name == "TextBoxName").FirstOrDefault();
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - List Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to store the text from the TextBoxes, you can use a dictionary like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

private void txt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string key = textBox.Name;
    string value = textBox.Text;
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
    else
    {
        dictionary[key] = value;
    }
}
```